# How to Modify Content in a Text Block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint-2013

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<td class="targetTD">
  <a href="http://foo.com">
    <span>content</span>
  </a>
  **Text I want to modify**
  <span>more content</span>
</td>
```

`targetTD` iterates a dynamic number of times depending on the content being rendered. For each iteration, I need to remove a substring of ": " from the beginning of the code in the text block. Unfortunately it's not in its own element and I don't have the ability to wrap it in a neat and tidy id/class. I did some searching and found some js I thought might do the trick:

```
<script>
var myString = $('.targetTD').html();
myString = myString.replace(': ','');
$('.targetTD').html(myString);
</script>
```

But that spits out a console error:

> Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference.

### Final Update (Solution)

Thanks to @Vaibhav for coming up with a fix! This script did the trick:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('.targetTD').each(function () {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\:\s/g, ''));
        });
    });

</script>
```

### Update 1

Thanks to @BenM I was able to stop the error from producing by using the following code:

```js
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.targetTD').html(function() { $(this).html().replace(': ', ''); });
});
</script>
```

Although I now don't get an error message, this still isn't removing the ": " from the text block. Any ideas on why this might be?

### Update 2

To provide some SharePoint specifics broadly, in response to a comment from @ElvisLikeBear:

- The specific task I'm trying to accomplish is hiding the column name from a grouped by list. In SP2010 this was easy to do by hiding the ms-gb class. In 2013, Microsoft has lumped in the expand/collapse button with this class so hiding it wholesale is not an option. I've successfully hid the span with the column name (in my code above, the span wrapped in the a), but the ": " is unhelpfully still in the text block, and now it's just floating there at the beginning of each category name.
- The code is being deployed at the page level as a snippet, using the Script Editor web part.

Comment: The error means `mystring` is empty.  Can you give an example of the html with the colon.

Comment: have you enclosed the td inside a table and tr?? if not then its not a valid html and jquery will not be able to find it. here's a working fiddle with your code. only extra thing is that i've enclosed it in table and tr http://jsfiddle.net/4262prrs/4/

Comment: are you wrapping code in `document.ready` so elements exist at time code runs? Important concept to understand

Comment: Also wrap your script in $(document).ready(function({//Script}); if you haven't already so it runs after all the elements have loaded.

Comment: Be careful with events and data attached to that HTML. You will lost them because you are removing DOM elements and creating new ones with same content.

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut there's no additional html in the colon - it's just text that right now reads ": Category Name"

Comment: @Sushil - Yes, it's all enclosed within a full page, I was just extracting the element I'm having trouble with.

Comment: can you try adding a console.log and check the console for the value of $('.targetID')? i think it is returning null or maybe an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brendan, issue with your code is you are replacing the ':' with '' but you are not assigning it to the same td again.

`Replace(':','')` function replaces only first occurance of ':'.Please follow my code. it will replace all the ':' with ''.

With reference from "targetTD iterates a dynamic number of times depending on the content being rendered"

I assume you need **foreach loop** to iterate over all the Tds.

Html :-

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="targetTD">
            <a href="http://foo.com">
                <span>content</span>
            </a>
            Test:Test1
            <span>more content</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="targetTD">
            <a href="http://foo.com">
                <span>content</span>
            </a>
            Test:Test1:test2
            <span>more content</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="targetTD">
            <a href="http://foo.com">
                <span>content</span>
            </a>
            Test:Test1:test3:test4
            <span>more content</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('.targetTD').each(function () {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\:/g, ''));
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Script is tested and works fine.

Comment: Thank you @Vaibhav! This almost works. It was successful in removing the : in the text box, but it also removed a : in the `<a href="http://foo.com">` tag and broke that link. I was able to successfully remove the offending ": " and avoid breaking the a tag by changing the regular expression in the replace function to /\:\s/g. Again, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DOM is ready:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.targetTD').html(function() { $(this).html().replace(': ', ''); });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks BenM! I'm not getting the error with this script, but it's also not replacing the text as I would hope. Any other ideas?

Comment: @BenM Unfortunately this doesn't work in SharePoint given the order of execution of SharePoint's own content

Answer (score 0):

Your tag indicates that this is executing on a SharePoint site which is why your code isn't firing. You need to deploy it properly for SharePoint.

You can do this in a solution or feature, or if it's a one page script you should use a script web part (called the Content Editor webpart in SharePoint 2010 and 2007), you could also add a code snippet to the page in SharePoint 2013.

You could also add the script into the  tag via [SharePoint designer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=35491) however I do not believe that would be best practice except in some very specific scenarios (however it would be the easiest approach for a non-SharePoint Devleoper).

Comment: Hi @ElvisLikeBear - Thanks for your comment. This actually is deployed as a snippet in a Script Editor web part. I'm trying to override the default SharePoint behavior of inserting "(COLUMN NAME): " before the specific category in a grouped by list, but not on all pages. In 2010 the text was wrapped conveniently in the ms-gb class, but in 2013 hiding that class with CSS now also hides the expand/collapse button.